# Multiplatform getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, windows, unix, path, separator

What file separators should I use in order to specify a path to resource? I run the packed program `java -jar program.jar`.

Currently I use the following loading

```
 inputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream(
                   File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "my.class");
```

On linux, it's correctly evaluated to `/resources/my.class` and the class is loaded. However, on Windows a `NullPointerException` is thrown. What is the correct use? I desperately need my program to be multiplatform.

I'm a bit confused since the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) informs that the path may start with `/` which isn't a Windows separator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resource path should always use '/' as it is not conceptually looking for a file path but a resource path within a class path entry.